# Flask can't find asset(css, js...) files of Vue-built app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask

I'm having an issue with vue's build settings and Flask's static_folder setting. I've tried several cases with Flask's static_folder setting, but the only one case among these three worked for me. And I can't see why.

```
// Build setting from vue.config.js

module.exports = {
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? '/dist/'
        : '/'
}
```

So my index.html has asset files' src and href as:

```
<script src=/dist/js/app.f4f6d455.js></script>
```

Here are my trials and results.

## Case 1: Error!

```
// Flask Setting
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = "./dist")

//Directory Structure
/project
    /dist
        /js
            app.f4f6d455.js
        index.html
    flask.py
```

result: Failed to load resource > http://127.0.0.1:5000/dist/js/app.f4f6d455.js

## Case 2: Error!

Copied assets into 'static/dist' since flask's default static_folder is 'static', and left dist folder intact to better clarify the error message.

```
// Flask Setting
app = Flask(__name__,
        template_folder = "./dist")

//Directory Structure
/project
    /dist
        /js
            app.f4f6d455.js
        index.html
    /static
        /dist
            /js
                app.f4f6d455.js
    flask.py
```

result: Failed to load resource > http://127.0.0.1:5000/dist/js/app.f4f6d455.js

## Case 3: Works!

Changed flask's static_folder to 'dist'

```
// Flask Setting
app = Flask(__name__,
    static_folder = "dist",
    template_folder = "./dist")

//Directory Structure
/project
    /dist
        /js
            app.f4f6d455.js
        index.html
    flask.py
```

I assumed that it was the matter of the root path when Flask tries to find its asset files. But Case 3 worked when case 2 didn't. if the root path of case 2 were 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/static', then it should have worked. Could anyone help me to understand this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might be getting mixed up with `publicPath` and `outputDir`. What URL path should be used to load the default page of your app? `http://localhost:5000/` or `http://localhost:5000/dist/`?

Comment: @Phil Thanks for your comment. The default page is 'index.html' which is at 'project/dist/index.html', plus my flask app says '/project' is its app.root_path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the assets for your front-end app to be served from `http://localhost:5000/dist`, you need to configure the `static_url_path` in your Flask app to match

```py
app = Flask(__name__, 
  static_folder="whatever-folder-you-want", 
  static_url_path="/dist")
```

You should also add a catch-all endpoint that routes all unmatched requests to your SPA

```py
@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def catch_all(path):
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")
```

See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/singlepageapplications/

---

If you wanted to use Flask's default static folder and path, you would need to change your Vue config to

```js
module.exports = {
  outputDir: "path/to/static", // the static folder in your Flask app
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? "/static/"
    : "/"
}
```

---

If you instead wanted to copy the `dist` folder into Flask's `static` folder after building your Vue app, change the `publicPath` to `/static/dist/`.

```js
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? "/static/dist/"
    : "/"
}
```

Comment: Thanks and for your tip! I guess the static folder settings between Vue and Flask should be explicitly matched. Even if the files exist in the designated folder of index.html, which is by Vue, and Flask's static folder is not specified for there, rendering fails. Thanks again!